# Display respective data based on the selected value Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte

I would like to display certain values based on the selected item.

Basically, I have a tab that toggles between schema names. When a person clicks one of the tabs, the respective table name under that schema will be displayed. That's done from my side.

Next, I would like to display the columns name of the selected table name. For example, if the user clicks table A, the page should display all the attributes names. I am new to svelte and I am not sure how to get it done. [image]

How do I display the respective table's column name upon clicking the table name?

SchemaNav.svelte

```
<script>
    let data = [];  //data for distinct schema name
    let activeItem; //holds the activeitem
    let name = []; //name for table name

    
    onMount(async () => {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/dist_schema.json');  //wait until the promise return result
        data = await res.json();
        activeItem = data[0];
        tabchange;
        // tableName();
    });
    const tabchange = (e) =>{
        activeItem = e.detail;
    }

    
    onMount(async () => {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/table_schema_name.json');  //wait until the promise return result
        name = await response.json();
        
    });
</script>

<Tabs {activeItem} {data} on:tabchange={tabchange}/>

{#if activeItem === "common"}
        <div class="content">
            <div class="tname">
                {#each name as names }
                    {#if names.table_schema === activeItem}
                        <ul>
                            <li>{names.table_name}</li>
                        </ul>
                    {/if}
                {/each}
            </div>
                    <Table />
    </div>  
{/if}
```

Table.svelte (the component that displays the column name in table form)

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
                <caption class="text-center">Column names</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Column Name</th>
                            <th>Data Type</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr}>  //this should be in a loop that display all the column name 
                            <td>parm_group_name</td>  //as of nw, I hardcoded it to see the value
                            <td>varchar(225)</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use createEventDispatcher from Svelte, but it was not successful. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data into the `Table` component and use that to render the columns

```html
<!-- Table.svelte -->
<script>
  export let data = []
</script>

...
{#each data as item}
  <tr><td>....</td></tr>
{/each}
```

You pass the data in from your parent component:

```html
<Table data={selectedData} />
```

Where `selectedData` is probably a subset of your `names` array or something ? (That part is not entirely clear to me from your question)

Comment: Sorry, may I ask what is the selectedData are u referring ?

Comment: the array with all the column names you want to display